# wrap v-slot element in different parent based on condition

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-slot

I have a template:

```
<template v-slot:title>
  {{ $t('title') }}
</template>
```

and a component:

```
<v-col cols="12">
 <h5 class="text-h5">
   <slot name="title" />
 </h5>
</v-col>
```

I want to wrap the slot with an `<h4>` tag only for one particular instance. I tried wrapping it inside the template, but it had no effect. How can I swap the element that wraps the slot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the type of tag you want to the component using a non mandatory prop and wrap the content into a dynamic component based on the passed value (in the example h2, h3 and h4 are correct values)

In the component template :

```html
<v-col cols="12">
  <component :is="wrapper" :class="`text-${wrapper}`">
    <slot name="title" />
  </component>
</v-col>
```

In the component script :

```js
props: {
  wrapper: {
    type     : String,
    required : false,
    default  : 'h5',
    validator: value => [ 'h2', 'h3', 'h4' ].includes(value)
  }
}
```